# Influence.measures usando o LOESS

Tags: r

Existe a possibilidade de usar o influence.measures a partir do resultado obtido com o LOESS? Por exemplo, seja o seguinte trecho:

```
x <- 1:120 
y <- sin(2*pi*x/period) + runif(length(x),-1,1)
plot(x,y, main="Sine Curve + 'Uniform' Noise")
y.loess <- loess(y ~ x, span=0.75, data.frame(x=x, y=y))
xl <- seq(min(x),max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/1000)
y.predict <- predict(y.loess, xl)
lines(xl,y.predict);
```

Quero saber quais são os outliers da amostra, a exemplo do obtemos no influence.measures. Usando o LOESS é possível saber?

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir sua rotina. Acho que estão faltando algumas informações. Quanto vale `period`? A função `loess()` é sua ou de alguma biblioteca?